# How do I fix PyXML?

Tags: python, xml

I have a set of python scripts that use PyXML.  The scripts used to work fine but now I get error.

How can I best repair this?

```
$ script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/mypath/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    from xml import xpath
  File "/cygdrive/c/data/code/xml/PyXML-0.8.4/xml/xpath/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import Context
  File "/cygdrive/c/data/code/xml/PyXML-0.8.4/xml/xpath/Context.py", line 15, in <module>
    import CoreFunctions
  File "/cygdrive/c/data/code/xml/PyXML-0.8.4/xml/xpath/CoreFunctions.py", line 20, in <module>
    from xml.xpath import Util, Conversions
  File "/cygdrive/c/data/code/xml/PyXML-0.8.4/xml/xpath/Conversions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from xml.utils import boolean
ImportError: cannot import name boolean
```

Then I tried to re-install PyXML..  This fails.

```
$ easy_install PyXML
Searching for PyXML
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyXML/
Reading http://www.python.org/sigs/xml-sig/
Best match: PyXML 0.8.4
Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/pyxml/PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz?modtime=1101741917&big_mirror=0
Processing PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz
Running PyXML-0.8.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZIX2LS/PyXML-0.8.4/egg-dist-tmp-5x8fiU
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no files found matching '*Makefile' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no files found matching '*.dsp' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*/CVS/*' found anywhere in distribution
     69 [main] python 3116 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap C:\cygwin\bin\cygcrypto-0.9.8.dll to same address as parent: 0x600000 != 0x910000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
00285F18  6102749B  (00285F18, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
00286208  6102749B  (61177B80, 00008000, 00000000, 61179977)
00287238  61004AFB  (611A136C, 6124060C, 00600000, 00910000)
End of stack trace
      2 [main] python 6800 fork: child 3116 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
error: Setup script exited with error: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve your problem specifically but I had a simillar problem which I googled and turned me here.
For whoever comes from google, The problem was with the pip install and the fix for that was:

you need to install it, You should find the file PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz on the web and then run:

```
pip install the PyXML tarball
```

Comment: This helped me in MacOS Catalina, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although I gave another solution it looks like you are using an unstable cygwin, I think the real problem is there and not in the PyXML package.

Try to reinstall cygwin OR:
Try installing Pyxml with windows installer from [here](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2009/10/31/windows-installer-for-pyxml-0-8-4-for-python-2-6-x/)